# How to find out what js a site uses?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking to develop my personal portfolio site, and would like to implement some sort of 'portfolio of work' area.

I want it to be simple and only display single images, however once the image is clicked a box should expand and show more content, such as design brief, tools used etc..

I have seen some examples of the kind of function I require, like eg http://themeforest.net/item/fraiche-flat-onepage-portfolio-bootstrap-template/full_screen_preview/5351761#portfolio and another here http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB04X111M

I would like to be able to find out what javascript plugins certain sites use so I can experiment with them myself. I have tried viewing the source and looking at the console but I find it difficult.

I have used Firebug and DevTools however I can't seem to figure out what js a carousel uses for example. I am able to view source and look at all the individual files that way. Was wondering if there was an easier way, or a browser add-on that would tell me when viewing the website?

If somebody could point me in the right direction I would be grateful.

Comment: Viewing the source is the only way to do it.

Comment: On Chrome, you can press F12 and click on sources. Other browsers have similar functionalities which allows you to read their source code. Good luck.

Comment: See if this helps https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/index

Comment: **CTRL** + **U** will show you the source and from there you can see everything the site uses.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! No idea why so many people have marked this question down? I provided as much info as possible and I was asking an honest question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very good plugin for firefox called **firebug** which shows all the JS files loaded for that particular page. In firebug scripts tab you can see that.

chrome comes with developer tools where you can find all the files loaded for that page. You can find this at Tool --> Developer Tools.[image: Check firebug image]

Answer (score 1):

Right click, Inspect Element or View Source. Look in head section.
You can also look under the Network and Resources tab in your dev tools in chrome, youll see the request to third party plugins too.

Comment: +1, but notice that there are many sites that include plugins **in the body** too.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an `http sniffer`(e.g. Fiddler\HttpAnalyzer etc.) and check what html\js\css etc content is downloaded.
After that, you will need to check the sources and find out how things are done.

Answer (score 0):

As others already suggested - view the page source and try to get desired plugin info from there.

There's also a great Chrome extension that'll allow you to instantly see all the javascript and server-side frameworks that the site runs on, it's called [Appspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/appspector/homgcnaoacgigpkkljjjekpignblkeae).